# All host(s) tried for query failed - com.datastax.driver.core.OperationTimedOutException

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, socket-timeout-exception

While performing Cassandra operations (Batch execution- insert and update operations on two tables) using spark job I am getting "**All host(s) tried for query failed - com. datastax. driver. core. OperationTimedOutException**" error.

**Cluster information:**
Cassandra 2.1.8.621 **|** DSE 4.7.1
spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 version - 1.2.0-rc1 **|**  cassandra-driver-core   version - 2.1.7
**Spark 1.2.1  | Hadoop 2.7.1** => 3 nodes
**Cassandra 2.1.8** => 5 nodes
**Each node having 28 gb memory and 24 cores**

While searching for it's solution I came across some discussions, which says you should **not use BATCHES**. Though I would like to find the root cause of this error.Also, How and from where to **set/get "SocketOptions. setReadTimeout"**, as this timeout limit must be greater than the Cassandra requests timeout as per standard guideline and to avoid possible errors.

Is the request_timeout_in_ms and the SocketOptions. setReadTimeout same?Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this timed out exception occurs at the very beginning of your insertion ? or after inserting few data in tables?

Comment: It is giving timeout exception only sometimes and it occurs after inserting few data.

Comment: Did you checked already inserted data ? is there any null values present in the primary key columns u defined?

Comment: Yeah.I have checked and there is no null value present in primary key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> While performing Cassandra operations (Batch execution- insert and
> update operations on two tables) using spark job I am getting "All
> host(s) tried for query failed - com. datastax. driver. core.
> OperationTimedOutException" error.

Directly from the [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.2.2/doc/FAQ.md#why-are-my-write-tasks-timing-out-failing):

#### Why are my write tasks timing out/ failing?

The most common cause of this is that Spark is able to issue write requests much more quickly than Cassandra can handle them. This can lead to GC issues and build up of hints. If this is the case with your application, try lowering the number of concurrent writes and the current batch size using the following options.

spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes

or in versions of the Spark Cassandra Connector greater than or equal to 1.2.0 set

spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec

which will allow you to control the amount of data written to C* per Spark core per second.

> you should not use BATCHES

This is not always true, the connector uses local token aware batches for faster reads and writes but this is tricky to get right in a custom app. In many cases async queries are better or just as good.

> setReadTimeout

This is a DataStax java driver [method](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/dcfb236839002c477541ddeb6fa38625cd2a1442/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/SocketOptions.java#L129). The connector takes care of this for you, no need to change it.

Comment: Thank you. I am using spark 1.2.1 with spark. Cassandra. output. throughput_mb_per_sec =2500 and concurrent. is written = 128. I will try to execute jobs by changing these two parameters.

Comment: I have changed spark.Cassandra.output. throughput_mb_per_sec  to 1000 and executed the job.Now the error is gone.But how can I decide the exact value for spark.Cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec?

Comment: Sorry,but this error is still there.After running some more jobs I am again getting this error.waiting for you reply.Thank you.

Comment: This is workload and hardware dependent, you need to tune it to a place that makes sense for your scenario. A good place to start would be by benchmarking cassandra (using cassandra-stress) with your datamodel and see how many mb per second it can handle. If you need more performance, add nodes.

Comment: check out -- www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema and www.sestevez.com/sestevez/CASTableSizer/

Comment: Will do that. Thank you.